# How to use JS global var in react App

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a JS global var in index.html page, I need to call this varaible in react JS app, I tried to store the results in localstorage, then call it from react app, for the first time "null" value returned when i call localstorage in react app, but if i refreshed the page the value displayed, how can i got the value from the first time, without refreshing the page?!

```
<script>
var langObject='';

$.getJSON('http://getJSON.com/en',    function(data) {
  langObject = data;
  localStorage.setItem('testObject',  JSON.stringify(data));
});
</script>
```

React App :

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


class HomePage extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        lang:localStorage.getItem('testObject'),
    }
}
render() {

return (

  <div className='home-page'>
    <h1>


      {/* {typeof langObject  +"  "}
      {  console.log( langObject )}} */}

    </h1>
  </div>
);
}
}

 export default HomePage;
```

OR is there any other way to get synced data from server before react render method called ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into lifecycle methods in React? You may need a promise since you are making a request and the response may come in too late.

However this may help you in your understanding regardless...

```
componentWillMount(){
   // Code to Execute before component renders
}
```

http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is data management and there are many ways to attack that problem. Global vars are definitely not the way to go, and `localStorage` can get you into trouble but is the right idea. I'd recommend what @machiael-paccione mentioned with React lifecycle methods, where you make that data call and store the value in the state of your component.

React actually recommends side effects be done in `componentDidMount`. Once you get your response and set the state using `this.setState` the component will naturally re-render, therefore fixing that initial state issue. What you'd want to do is render something like a loading bar when your state variable is null (initial state) and display stuff once you get it back.